# Video Chat App With WebRTC issue with browser not showing other users in the room

Tags: socket.io, webrtc

I'm trying to build a Video Chat App With WebRTC from a tutorial. This is my second time working with socket.io. The video chat room is suppose to show a video of any user that comes to that room. When I log on to the video chat room, my video shows up fine but when I log on to the same room from another browser the new users video does not show up in the other browser. The first browser does show the new user's id in the console but doesn't display the video of the new user that just joined in.

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
})

const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {
   addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)
    
    myPeer.on('call', call =>   {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })     
})
    
    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream) 
    })
})


myPeer.on('open', id => {
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    console.log('User connected:' + userId)

})


function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
    call.on('close', () => {
        video.remove()
    })
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

The code that should make this work is:

```
    myPeer.on('call', call =>   {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })     
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been working on this on issue all day with no success.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out when the 'user-connected' event triggers, calling connectToNewUser immediately fails. setTimeout of a second before calling connectToNewUser fixed my problem.

```
socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
  // user is joining
  setTimeout(() => {
    // user joined
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
  }, 1000)
})
```